# Algorithm to find whether ray is clockwise, counterclockwise, or neither

Tags: c#, vector

I'm looking for an algorithm that figures out whether a particular array is clockwise or counter-clockwise, or neither. If it matters, I'm using C#.

The input variables are X position, Y position, and a normalized (1 unit long) Ray (list of X and Y components, from -1 to 1) in an arbitrary direction, with its source located at the given point.

The output variable is some kind of type which can have up to 3 states, such as a byte with the return possibilities being 0, 1, or 2, to represent clockwise, counterclockwise, or neither.

This diagram should help:

[image: Ray Output Example]

Rays in the green area should return counterclockwise, rays in the red area should return clockwise, and the blue area should return neither. This shape rotates depending on the position, so one of the blue corners will always be pointing towards the center. These rays may be imperfect, therefore the margin of error should be large, a full 90 degrees for each "quadrant" should be good.

I don't really have the math skills to implement this myself, so that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I managed to solve my issue by just comparing two angles. I figured it was easier to work the problem forwards twice and compare the answers than to try and work the problem backwards.

```
private sbyte GetCircumferenceDirection (Vector2 pos, Vector2 dir) {
    float angleHit = Mathf.Atan2 (pos.y, pos.x);
    float angleNormal = Mathf.Atan2 (pos.y + dir.y, pos.x + dir.x);
    float angleDiff = angleNormal - angleHit;
    if (angleDiff > 0.001) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (angleDiff < -0.001) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

...where Vector2 is an object containing X and Y variables.

Thanks anyway for your answer JaeWoo So, even though I didn't understand it.

Comment: Note: This answer uses **Unity C#** with Vector2 and Mathf specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem like below.

1. First, calculate region of x,y point
2. Second, classify this region

Here is Code.

```
namespace ClockWise_Stackoverflow
{
    public enum State { ClockWise, CounterClockWise, Neither }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rd = new Random();
            var xyInput = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                                        .Select(f => new double[2] 
                                                      {         
                                                       rd.NextDouble(),  
                                                       rd.NextDouble()
                                                      }
                                         .ToState())
                                         .ToList();           
        }

    }

    public static class Extension
    {
        public static State ToState(
            this double[] xy)
        {
            var x = xy[0];
            var y = xy[1];
            if (x * y <= 0) return State.Neither;
            else if (x > 0) return State.CounterClockWise;
            else if (x < 0) return State.ClockWise;
            else return State.Neither;
        }
    }
}
```

This main method is same as below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rd = new Random();
        List<State> xyOutput = new List<State>();

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            double[] input = new double[] 
                                    {
                                        rd.NextDouble(),
                                        rd.NextDouble()
                                    };
            State currentState = input.ToState();
            xyOutput.Add( currentState );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why must Enumerable.Range be used? What does `=>` mean?